# MPI Scatter with Array of Objects in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

The function prototype of `MPI_Scatter` in C++ looks like:

```
MPI_Scatter(
    void* send_data,
    int send_count,
    MPI_Datatype send_datatype,
    void* recv_data,
    int recv_count,
    MPI_Datatype recv_datatype,
    int root,
    MPI_Comm communicator)
```

For example, we can scatter an array of doubles (`send_data`) across procs from the root process (0) like so:

```
MPI_Scatter(send_data, send_count, MPI::DOUBLE, recv_data, recv_count, MPI::DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Where all procs now have the split array in `recv_data`.

But now, what if `send_data` is an object array? For example, `send_data` is defined by

`SomeClass *send_data`

Instead of `MPI::DOUBLE`, should be used for the datatype in `MPI_Scatter` in this case?

Comment: note MPI works with data in contiguous memory (e.g. not array of pointers to objects). It is up to you to create a derived datatype matching your class. Since you are using C++, you might want to have a look at Boost.MPI and Boost.Serialization. This is no standard MPI, but these libraries might do some black magic to transfer c++ objects without you having to manually create a derived datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the size of the continous memory part you can send everything as the `MPI_CHAR`. This might be a very flexible way of sending anything you want. I would think about it like a text/binary file where you know exactly how you keep your data. The idea is similar to overloading `operator=` for being able to copy the object. For instance, you can create stringstream to which you write significant content of the class(might be full content). Then convert it to the `string` / `const char *` using: `str().c_str()` and voila, all can be send as the `MPI_CHAR`. Similar thing can be done for binary data. If you choose this way, be sure you keep the `const char *` in the memory while the communication is not finished.

In this case, the received data need to be processed like a text/binary file to build up again your array of objects. This, I guess will be relatively easy comparing to other ways of transfering complex objects and does not require additional libraries.